# portable opengpg?

Tags: portable, openpgp

I would like a portable opengpg binary/frontend for windows (bonus linux as well) so i can decrypt emails written to me at any time. So far all the programs i found requires installation and seems to copy my private key. I rather not have my private key copy which is why i'd like it to be on a usb pen and to select it when i need to.

What options do i have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use portable Thunderbird with the Enigmail plugin:
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Running_from_a_USB_drive_(Thunderbird)#Portable_Thunderbird
Apparently it also runs under wine!

Edit: for just encrypting/decrypting [this](http://ppgp.sourceforge.net/) tool might work, but I have no experience with it.

Comment: What if i was to decrypt a PM someone left me on a forum. Can it decrypt that? What if i want to send an encrypted PM and i dont have the user email (but obviously i'd have a public key)

Comment: I have never heard of a forum that delivers encrypted PM's... Is this a hypothetical question? Thunderbird with Enigmail just does email messages (like you asked ;) )

Comment: Well i mean with a frontend i can type my message, choose a key to encrypt it to and it gives me a copy/pastable text. I put that in an email, txt file, whatever i want and i copy/paste it back to a frontend and use a private key to decrypt into the original text. I'm asking if i wanted to could i save the message as a txt file, doc, pm, etc. I don't necessarily need to send/recv the messages as email?

Comment: @acidzombie24 updated the answer

Comment: +1 and accepted. However this may be weird to people but i don't actually have java installed.